# Average with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the exact average of a variable.
Currently I have this query: (simplified):

```
select ID , Group_ID, Chargeability,Job_No_, Group_Charg FROM Data1


ID      Group ID        Chargeability       Job No_     Group Chargeability
1             a             90                c1                 88.11
1             a             90                c2                 88.11
1             a             90                c3                 88.11
1             a             90                c4                 88.11
2             a             85.6              c8                 88.11
2             a             85.6              c17                88.11
2             a             85.6              c6                 88.11
```

The average calculated is not the actual one. The Chargability is fixed for each ID so that the average should not take into consideration the number of rows per ID because it is just a replacement of the value as we have lotz of job_No per each ID.

I.e I would like to have `Group_chargeability` = (90+85.6)/2 instead of (90*4)+(85.6*3)/7 as currently is doing.

The query is made up of several sub-queries, some of them also calling function. This is why I cannot use group by to try to solve the issue I have.

Comment: `avg(distinct chargeability) over (partition by GROUP_ID)`?  assumes you want the average by group...  results in 87.8 I believe. though It may mishandle how you want to avg if ID 1 and 3 both had same chargeability in the same group...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `AVG` function with a `SUB QUERY`

```
SELECT d.ID, d.Group_ID, d.Chargeability, d.Job_No_, 
AVG(SELECT MIN(sub.Chargeability) 
 FROM Data1 sub
 WHERE sub.id = d.id AND sub.Job_No_ = d.Job_No_
 GROUP BY sub.ID) AS GROUP_Chargeability
FROM Data1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a joined subquery like this:

```
SELECT d.ID, d.GROUP_ID, d.CHARGEABILITY, d.JOB_NO_, d2.charges 
FROM Data1 d LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT DISTINCT ID, GROUP_ID, AVG(CHARGEABILITY) AS CHARGES FROM Data1) d2 
    ON d2.ID = d.ID AND d2.GROUP_ID = d.GROUP_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the average chargability overall:

```
select avg(Chargeability) as avgChargeability
from (select id, avg(Chargeability) as Chargeability
      from t
      group by id
     ) id;
```

You can bring this value onto each row using `join` or a subquery.